# Accessing dictionary/predictive text file on Android

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-application

I've been trying to find the location of the user dictionary text file on Android (Razr on ICS). There have been a handful of posts that say it isn't accesible to phones that aren't rooted.

Is there way to access the user dictionary file(.udb??) on non-rooted phones? If not is there a way to append a file on the users internal storage that will add to the dictionary file?